# "Unlink of old file failed" - Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans-8, unlink

I am trying to execute a batch file from a java application using netbean-8.2

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start build.bat");
```

The batch file contains code to pull the git changes

```
git pull
```

When I run the java app, the cmd prompt opens and runs the batch file successfully, but the git pull command fails, throwing the error,

```
Unlink of old file 'file.txt' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

I am able to git pull successfully if I close the java app and run the batch file separately.

I tried adding -J-Dosgi.locking=none in netbeans.conf file, but was unsuccessful.

Is there a way to fix this problem without closing the java application?

Comment: I got that fixed. Thanks to the function..."System.gc"